# Need help on SQL statement

Tags: sql

Hello i am getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING" on the following SQL Statement. Any help thanks

```
$result2 = ($con,SELECT 
                       Customers.CustomerId, JrnlHdr.Reference, JrnlRow.DistNumber, LineItem.ItemId, LineItem.ItemDescription 
                 FROM "JrnlHdr", "JrnlRow", "Customers", "LineItem" 
                 WHERE JrnlHdr.POSOisClosed = 0 
                   AND JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder 
                   AND JrnlHdr.CustVendId = Customers.CustomerRecordNumber 
                   AND JrnlRow.temRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber 
                   AND JrnlHdr.JrnlKey_Journal = 11);
```

Comment: I just have to ask, what database API are you using here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query should be a string, use quotes:

```
$result2 = ($con,'SELECT Customers.CustomerId, JrnlHdr.Reference, JrnlRow.DistNumber, LineItem.ItemId, LineItem.ItemDescription FROM "JrnlHdr", "JrnlRow", "Customers", "LineItem" WHERE JrnlHdr.POSOisClosed = 0 AND JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder AND JrnlHdr.CustVendId = Customers.CustomerRecordNumber AND JrnlRow.temRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber AND JrnlHdr.JrnlKey_Journal = 11');
```

However this code will still result in an other error. You need to call a function to query the database, for example [`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT Customers.CustomerId, JrnlHdr.Reference, JrnlRow.DistNumber, LineItem.ItemId, LineItem.ItemDescription FROM "JrnlHdr", "JrnlRow", "Customers", "LineItem" WHERE JrnlHdr.POSOisClosed = 0 AND JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder AND JrnlHdr.CustVendId = Customers.CustomerRecordNumber AND JrnlRow.temRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber AND JrnlHdr.JrnlKey_Journal = 11');
```